# Union type function "overloading" not working

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I tried to "overload" a function by setting it to a union function type so that the type of the given parameter sets the type of the member `data` in the returned object. But it throws an error:

```ts
type FN1 = (a: string) => {data: string};
type FN2 = (b: number) => {data: number};
    
const fn: FN1 | FN2 = c => ({data: c});
    
fn('some string');
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <= Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

The type of `fn` is displayed as

```ts
const fn: (arg0: never) => {data: string} | {data: number}
```

Why is the parameter of type `never`? Is there some other way to make it possible?

[SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cdn-zmhwk?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for generics since your return type can be easily typed from your input type.

For any value:

```
const fn = <T>(c: T): {data: T} => ({data: c});
```

For string and number only:

```
const fn = <T extends string | number>(c: T): {data: T} => ({data: c});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your need, I would simply use a generic function:

```
function fn1<T>(data: T) {
  return { data };
}
```

Of course it can be solved with function overloading as well (note: this would not work in your codesanbox becaues eslint has an error with redeclaring the function, but it is valid in typescript and it is an error in eslint):

```
function fn1(data:string): {data: string};
function fn1(data:number): {data: number};
function fn1(data: any): any {
    return {data};
}

fn1("some string");
fn1(1);
```